# Display numbers with 20 in front of var

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How can I display numbers with 20 in front of the var? (i.e. `\20172018\INV` instead of `\1718\INV`)

Comment: You might want to check this out, and edit your post: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is this related to Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

Insert your `20` at particular places by building a new string from substrings. Assuming your variable is in a string called `s`:

```
string newString = s.Substring(0,1) + "20" + s.Substring(1,2) + "20" + s.Substring(3,6);
```

Comment: This assumes that the position of the digits is fixed.

Comment: @J.D. Yep and nothing in the question suggests otherwise.  Your regex solution is nice too.

Comment: Fair enough... LOL

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine where the 20 goes? Is it after every two digits??

The regular expression `var r = Regex.Replace("1718\\NV", "\\d{2}", "20$&");` for example assumes that you are looking for 2 digits each time (that's what the {2} means) and places the 20 in front of each pair of digits. It returns `20172018\\NV`. If you want to place the 20 in front of each digit separately, then modify the RegEx pattern (2nd parameter). `var r = Regex.Replace("1718\\NV", "\\d", "20$&");` returns `201207201208\\NV`